# ggplot2 missing aesthetics with dichotomous variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics

**Edit: I have plotted a likert scale with 15  different categories (Q002_1 - Q002_15) to answer, see graph down below.**

What I now want is to plot this graph (code below) as dichotomous variable with ggplot2, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779220/ordinal-variable-to-become-dichotomous/) for further details.

I get the following error message:

> Error: stat_bin requires the following missing aesthetics: x

I know that I do not see the painful obvious here. Can anyone help me out?

Code:

```
competence_bachelor_dich <- competence_bachelor # dichotomous variable

levels(competence_bachelor_dich) <- list("0" = c("insignificant", "2", "3"),
                         "1" = c("8", "9", "very relevant"))

ggplot(rawdata, aes(x = competence_bachelor_dich)) + 
  geom_histogram() + xlab("") + ylab("Number of participants") + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = "0", "1") + 
  ggtitle("How do you rate your skills gained with the Bachelor's?") + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black"), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black")) 

ggsave((filename = "competence_bachelor_dich.pdf"), 
        scale = 1, width = par("din")[1], 
        height = par("din")[2], units = c("in", "cm", "mm"), 
        dpi = 300, limitsize = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Add the output of `dput(head(rawdata))` to your question.

Comment: Please explain your dataset. Looking at `example.ods` from your previous question, what do the columns mean? E.g., what is the difference between Q002_02, _03, ... _15 ??? Also, none of the values are "very relevant" or "insignificant", although there are 1's and 10's.

Comment: Done. I have edit my original post.

Answer (score 2):

`competence_bachelor_dich` is not a column in the `rawdata` data.frame. If everything eslse is the way it should be your code should work if you add `rawdata$competence_bachelor_dich <- competence_bachelor_dich`

Comment: I get instead the following error message: Error: stat_bin requires the following missing aesthetics: x